# php - separate class method declarations and defintions?

Tags: php, oop, class

I'm comming from C++ and from all I've read in the manual and code examples, none seem to separate a class method declaration from its definition. Is this not possible in PHP? Dosn't this lead to very hard-to-read and cluttery interfaces?

Thanks

EDIT:
I want something like this:

```
class MyClass
{
    public function Foo();

};

MyClass::Foo()
{
    echo "O-hoy!";
}
```

Comment: I don't understand the question. Please give an example of something you would be able to do in C++, but not in PHP.

Comment: In C++ its possible to declare class prototype before its implemention. And class isnt becoming abstract.

Comment: What you want is impossible in PHP, you'll have to use interfaces (see also my answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This concept is not necessary in PHP. If you want to get a clean interface, you might define one. http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.interfaces.php

Answer (score 2):

When not using `interface`s, you are right. Like in Java, the class definition is the declaration. However, (also like Java), you have the `interface` available that you can use:

From the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.interfaces.php):

```
interface iTemplate
{
    public function setVariable($name, $var);
    public function getHtml($template);
}

// Implement the interface
// This will work
class Template implements iTemplate
{
    private $vars = array();
    ...
}
```

it is perfectly legal to put them in different files. The class definition though, will always be in one file. You cannot use the `partial` keyword as you can in C#.